# How to change source folder for Kotlin project in Gradle

Tags: kotlin, gradle

By default it uses `src/main/kotlin` and `src/test/kotlin` as a source folders.

I would like to change it to just `src` and use it for both app and test code in the same folder.

What do I need to change in the gradle config to achieve that?

```
plugins {
  id("org.jetbrains.kotlin.jvm") version "1.3.72"
  application
}

repositories {
  jcenter()
}

application {
  mainClassName = "al.MainKt"
}
```

Comment: Why????????????

Comment: @AbhijitSarkar because I don't like things like `/com/a/b/c/enterprise/factory/c/d`, although I know such style popular in Java. :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

see https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/building_java_projects.html#sec:compile

```
sourceSets {
    main {
        java {
            setSrcDirs(listOf("src"))
        }
    }

    test {
        java {
            setSrcDirs(listOf("test"))
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can omit the common root package without messing with Gradle at all.

> In pure Kotlin projects, the recommended directory structure follows
> the package structure with the common root package omitted. For
> example, if all the code in the project is in the org.example.kotlin
> package and its subpackages, files with the org.example.kotlin package
> should be placed directly under the source root, and files in
> org.example.kotlin.network.socket should be in the network/socket
> subdirectory of the source root.

https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/coding-conventions.html#directory-structure

Comment: this is not a answer to the question. the question is about using a shorter source root, and your link is about shorter paths under the source root.

Comment: @globalmatador I’ve to say that you didn’t understand the question at all. You’re welcome to post an answer yourself if you think you can be more helpful.